# UICollectionViewCell size issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm experiencing a layout issue with my collectionView. I've set the cell sizes to be different for the first cell (indexPath.row == 0) but then the same afterwards.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    return CGSizeMake(290.0f, 168.0f);
}
    else {
    return CGSizeMake(144.0f, 114.5f);
    }
}
```

So that works fine most of the time but when I reload my collectionView:

```
[viewController.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
```

The first cell becomes same size as all the other cells.

I didn't think this would be an issue, any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the cell is the wrong size, as opposed to the contents of the cell being the wrong size?  This can happen as a result of mangled/missing autoresize masks and/or constraints since the cells are reused.

Comment: Hey @David is there anyway to check this? I'm using a custom cell but not using any resizing masks as far as I can see. Not using storyboard or NIB's, just code.

Comment: My favorite to double-check view sizes is change the background colors to something really obnoxious.  Are you intending to change the width as well as the height?  I can see where that might cause a standard flow layout controller some heartburn, I'd hope not, but...

Comment: You've got something going on somewhere other than in this function.  If I set up a similar experiment (albeit using storyboards, I'm lazy) the results are more or less as expected.

Comment: Hey @David! That was exactly it!! Had it to clear background color and then changed it to black and it is indeed the contents that are being sized wrongly!